# Magento 2 How to get products details with qty calling products endpoint?

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

Magento 2 How to get products details with qty calling products endpoint?
I need to get the qty from the products endpoint.

Comment: With graphql or rest api?

Comment: Using rest api - default magento endpoint /V1/products